# Stata: Variable type (8-digit numbers)

Tags: excel, type-conversion, stata

```
input a
88888888
99999999
end
export excel a.xlsx, replace
```

Then, if I open the excel file, the numbers are shown as 8.89e+07 and 1.00e+08. How can I restore these to the original numbers. Do I have to do this in Excel? Is there any way to prevent Stata from converting those numbers to the "scientific" format?

Comment: Just asking the obvious, but are you sure it's not just a number Format change in Excel?

Comment: I think this is a problem in Stata. 99999999 in Stata is exported as 1.00E+08 in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of your `input` command is to read those numbers into variables of `float` type. But there aren't enough bits in a `float` to hold 99999999 exactly.  This is well documented.

See e.g. the help for `data types`:

"`float`s have about 7 digits of accuracy; the magnitude of the number does not matter.  Thus, 1234567 can be stored perfectly as a `float`, as can 1234567e+20.  The number 123456789, however, would be rounded to 123456792.  In general, this rounding does not matter.

If you are storing identification numbers, the rounding could matter.  If the
identification numbers are integers and take 9 digits or less, store them as `long`s;
otherwise, store them as `double`s.  `double`s have 16 digits of accuracy."

So you degraded your data by using an inappropriate data type. That is the issue, not `export excel`.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. I fixed this problem as follows: .recast double a .format %11.0g a .recode a (100000000=99999999)

Comment: Pleased that you fixed your problem, but for the future, note that `recast double` will never restore lost bits. You need to use appropriate data types from the outset.